# Getting this error while binning for plot: TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'

Tags: bins

bins=[-30, 0, 30, 60, 90, 120]
group_names =["-30 to 0", "0 to 30", "30 to 60", "60 to 90", "Over 100"]
AccidentData_2021["Temperature(F)"]=pd.cut(AccidentData_2021["Temperature(F)"], bins, labels=group_names)
AccidentData_2021

Expecting bar plot

Answer (score 0):

bins=[-30, 0, 30, 60, 90, 120]
group_names =["-30 to 0", "0 to 30", "30 to 60", "60 to 90", "Over 100"]
AccidentData_2021["Temperature(F)"]=pd.cut(AccidentData_2021["Temperature(F)"], bins=bins, labels=group_names)
AccidentData_2021

Comment: Put your code into the code tag